# Understanding ASP.NET Eval() and Bind()

Tags: asp.net, eval, bind

Can anyone show me some absolutely minimal ASP.NET code to understand `Eval()` and `Bind()`?

It is best if you provide me with two separate code-snippets or may be web-links.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

For read-only controls they are the same. For 2 way databinding, using a datasource in which you want to update, insert, etc with declarative databinding, you'll need to use `Bind`.

Imagine for example a GridView with a `ItemTemplate` and `EditItemTemplate`. If you use `Bind` or `Eval` in the `ItemTemplate`, there will be no difference. If you use `Eval` in the `EditItemTemplate`, the value will not be able to be passed to the `Update` method of the `DataSource` that the grid is bound to.

---

UPDATE: I've come up with this example:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Data binding demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:GridView 
            ID="grdTest" 
            runat="server" 
            AutoGenerateEditButton="true" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
            DataSourceID="mySource">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Eval("Name") %>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox 
                            ID="edtName" 
                            runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' 
                        />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </form>

    <asp:ObjectDataSource 
        ID="mySource" 
        runat="server"
        SelectMethod="Select" 
        UpdateMethod="Update" 
        TypeName="MyCompany.CustomDataSource" />
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the definition of a custom class that serves as object data source:

```
public class CustomDataSource
{
    public class Model
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Model> Select()
    {
        return new[] 
        {
            new Model { Name = "some value" }
        };
    }

    public void Update(string Name)
    {
        // This method will be called if you used Bind for the TextBox
        // and you will be able to get the new name and update the
        // data source accordingly
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        // This method will be called if you used Eval for the TextBox
        // and you will not be able to get the new name that the user
        // entered
    }
}
```

Comment: GridView is a complex control. Can you plz explain it for me with simpler controls like textbox or the page itself?

Comment: Simpler controls don't have `DataSource` property.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov do Bind or Eval only work with IEnumerables?  Can I use this if my source is a DataTable?

Answer (score 36):

The question was answered perfectly by Darin Dimitrov, but since **ASP.NET 4.5**, there is now a better way to set up these bindings to replace* `Eval()` and `Bind()`, taking advantage of the **strongly-typed bindings**.

***Note:** this will only work if you're **not** using a `SqlDataSource` or an `anonymous object`. It requires a Strongly-typed object (from an **EF model** or any other class).

This code snippet shows how `Eval` and `Bind` would be used for a `ListView` control (`InsertItem` needs `Bind`, as explained by Darin Dimitrov above, and `ItemTemplate` is read-only (hence they're labels), so just needs an `Eval`):

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Id" InsertItemPosition="LastItem" SelectMethod="ListView1_GetData" InsertMethod="ListView1_InsertItem" DeleteMethod="ListView1_DeleteItem">
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        <li>
            Title: <asp:TextBox ID="Title" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Title") %>'/><br />         
            Description: <asp:TextBox ID="Description" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>' /><br />        
            <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" Text="Insert" CommandName="Insert" />        
        </li>
    </InsertItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            Title: <asp:Label ID="Title" runat="server" Text='<%#  Eval("Title") %>' /><br />
            Description: <asp:Label ID="Description" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' /><br />        
            <asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" CausesValidation="false"/>
        </li>
      </ItemTemplate>
```

From **ASP.NET 4.5+**, data-bound controls have been extended with a new property `ItemType`, which points to the type of object you're assigning to its data source.

```
<asp:ListView ItemType="Picture" ID="ListView1" runat="server" ...>
```

`Picture` is the strongly type object (from EF model). We then replace:

```
Bind(property) -> BindItem.property
Eval(property) -> Item.property
```

So this:

```
<%# Bind("Title") %>      
<%# Bind("Description") %>         
<%#  Eval("Title") %> 
<%# Eval("Description") %>
```

Would become this:

```
<%# BindItem.Title %>         
<%# BindItem.Description %>
<%# Item.Title %>
<%# Item.Description %>
```

**Advantages over Eval & Bind**:

- IntelliSense can find the correct property of the object your're working with[image]
- If property is renamed/deleted, you will get an error before page is viewed in browser
- External tools (requires full versions of VS) will correctly rename item in markup when you rename a property on your object

**Source**: from [this](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Beginning-ASP-NET-4-5-1-in-C-and-VB.productCd-111884677X.html) excellent book

Comment: How does the `<%#` syntax compare to `<%=` then?

Comment: [This](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dancre/2007/02/13/the-difference-between-and-in-asp-net/) explains the difference of `<%#` and `<%=`.

Comment: How the hell did I found out about this feature just now?!? Brilliant