# Difference between Eval and Bind

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Understanding asp.net Eval() and Bind()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778221/understanding-asp-net-eval-and-bind)

```
    <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataKeyField="CustomerID" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        CustomerID:
        <asp:Label ID="CustomerIDLabel" runat="server" 
            Text='<%# Eval("CustomerID") %>' />

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Whats the difference between Eval and Bind?

Comment: Also if you ask google it has the answer too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Eval method evaluates late-bound data expressions in the templates of data-bound controls such as the GridView, DetailsView, and FormView controls and the Bind method is typically used with input controls such as the TextBox control rendered by a GridView row in edit mode.

Answer (score 2):

Have you [searched](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Whats%20the%20difference%20between%20Eval%20and%20Bind?) for the answer before asking?

> Eval is a protected method defined on
>   the TemplateControl class, from which
>   the Page class is derived.  Bind is a
>   new ASP.NET 2.0 databinding keyword.
>   It's not a method of any specific
>   class.
>
> Eval is used for unidirectional
>   (readonly) data binding, while Bind is
>   for bi-directional (editable)
>   databinding.

Answer (score 1):

Eval is used in read only way... so only take the data and display it. 
Bind is user for two ways databinding...

Answer (score 1):

It means the Label `CustomerIDLabel` will get the Value from the Database where the Column name is `CustomerID`