# What is the purpose of adding BindableAttribute on a property of a custom control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, custom-controls

I have seen that BindableAttribute is used to decorate public properties in custom controls.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ft8ts94a%28v=vs.90%29) briefly mentions that it provides the ability to control the binding direction and whether binding is supported at design time.

```
public class MyControl : Panel
{
    [Bindable(BindableSupport.No, BindingDirection.OneWay)]
    public string MyString { get; set; }
}

var myControl = new MyControl();
var myString = myControl.MyString;
```

Questions:

1) I set `BindableSupport` to No, however I could still do this in markup (.aspx).
What does `BindableSupport` affect then? Does it hide the property in the toolbox?

```
<cc:MyControl runat="server" MyString="something" />
```

2) How does one-way binding and two-way binding work in the context of custom controls and ASP.NET?

Would appreciate any inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My findings so far:

1) `BindableSupport` is related to data-binding functionality provided by ASP.NET. E.g. `Page.DataBind()`, `<%# Bind("MyProperty") %>`, `<%# Eval ("MyProperty") %>` and so on. 
+1 for @walther's answer.

2) Two-way binding in ASP.NET is the ability to retain modifications to data-bound values on postback. This [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778221/understanding-asp-net-eval-and-bind) provides more details. `Bind` is two-way, while `Eval` is one-way.

Answer (score 1):

I believe MSDN is clear enough about this. It may be brief in your eyes, but it's sufficient.
This attribute is used for BINDING. Assigning a string to your variable isn't considered a binding.

This is for instance binding:

```
myGridView.DataSource = myList;
myGridView.DataBind();
```

This isn't:

```
myGridView.ID = "blablabla";
```

Please, see this link for more info, don't see a reason to duplicate an existing learning source here...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx

UPDATE:

For asp.net this link may be more illustrative:

http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/HOW%20TO%20Create%20an%20Editable%20View%20with%20Two-Way%20Data%20Binding.ashx

Comment: Thanks for answering my first question, I now understand the real meaning of 'binding'. About my second question, the MSDN resource you mentioned talks about WPF, I know how two-way binding is relevant to thick client apps in WPF. But how does two-way binding work in a web environment like ASP.NET? E.g. Suppose I change my property on the server, it wouldn't affect the control rendered on the browser automatically. I don't think this is obvious, if it is, I will delete my question. Thanks.

Comment: @channs,please, see the update. Hopefully it will help you to understand how to do that :)