# Why I have to use Eval to access data source's second level properties of a GridView and not Bind in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, eval, bind

Suppose I have a GridView whose data source is a list of type Meeting. Every Meeting object has a property of type Employee, and at the same time every Employee has a Name property.
If I want to show the name of the Employee in a GridView, I should do this:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Employee.Name") %>' runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

My question: Why I'm not able to do the same thing with Bind? When trying to display the property of a property using Bind, I get a compilation error. What are the differences in this case about using Eval or Bind?

English is not my first language, sorry for all possible mistakes.

Comment: You can do it with [eval](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130351/gridview-bound-with-with-properties-of-nested-class)

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to display data on the screen from DataSource it’s enough to use `Eval`

But if you need to edit data inside of Grid you have to use `Bind` method. Because it provides two way binding you can read data from DataSource and you can write data back

If you try to edit some row in Data Grid and want to make some changes in code behind class in `OnUdpdating` event, data with `Eval` method will not be available instead of `Bind` method.

The difference between these two is that `Eval` is used for read only purpose and `Bind` is used for read/edit purpose. For example `Eval` can be used to bind the Text property of an asp.net Label control whereas `Bind` can be used to bind the asp.net TextBox control so that it can be edited to meet some requirement.

For more info see [Mr.Darin Dimitrov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778221/understanding-asp-net-eval-and-bind) answer

Comment: Ok, I understand that. I don't want to make any updates, I just want to show the data. The thing is if I use Bind instead of Eval in my previous example I get a compilation error. I thought that if I don't want to do any updates there is no difference between using Eval or Bind, and this is true most of the time, but if I want to display the property of a property, then I get an error when using Bind.